# Can I install SQL Server 2005 on the Windows Starter Edition?

Tags: sql

Can I install SQL Server 2005 on a netbook running the Windows Starter Edition?

Comment: Have you read the [How to ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) page? Particularly "Do hour homework"? Sorry, but -1 for confusing us with Google.

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is no, but if you use Orca to modify the msi packages, you may be able to get past the OS check and install, but the program may not run.

Answer (score 1):

No. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Not sure which OS you're using, but for Windows 7 you can upgrade for a reasonable price. See [here](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/productID.228661800).